# Select2 Not active

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-select2

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("#btn-tambah-form").click(function(){ 
            var jumlah = parseInt($("#jumlah-form").val()); 
            var nextform = jumlah + 1;

            $("#insert-form").append(
                "<div class='row mb-10 p-10'>" +
                "   <div class='input-group col-md-2'>" +
                "          <?php $result = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT * FROM produk');?>" +
                "          <?php $jsArray = 'var idproduk = new Array();\n';?>" +
                "          <select class='form-control select2' id=\'idproduk"+nextform+"\' name=\'idproduk[]\' onchange=\'changeProduk"+nextform+"(this.value),sum();\' required>" +
                "          <option></option>" +
                "          <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {?>" +
                "               <?php echo '<option value=\'' . $row['idproduk'] . '\'>' . $row['produk_nama'] .  '</option>';?>" +
                "               <?php$jsArray .= 'idproduk[\'' . $row['idproduk'] . '\'] = {harga_beli:\'' . addslashes($row['harga_beli']) . '\',produk_satuan:\'' . addslashes($row['produk_satuan']) . '\'};\n';?>" +
                "          <?php }?>" +
                "              </select>" +
                "   </div>" +
                "</div>");
            $("#jumlah-form").val(nextform);
        });
        
        $("#btn-reset-form").click(function(){
            $("#insert-form").html(""); 
            $("#jumlah-form").val("1");
        });
    });
</script>
```

can someone help me. why my select2 not active when i put them on javascript.
when i put them outside java they can run correct.

please help me how to solve this code.

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with backslashed quotes, remove them. It should be all.

```
<select class='form-control select2' id='idproduk"+nextform+"' name='idproduk[]' onchange='changeProduk"+nextform+"(this.value),sum();' required>" +
```

Comment: that not work sir. i already do that but the result is same

Comment: Than there is missing space between <?php$jsArray. The rest is syntactically ok. If still doesnt work, problem is elsewhere

Comment: "   <div class='input-group  col-md-1'>" +
    "       <select class='form-control select2' name='pajak[]' id='pajak"+nextform+"' style='width: 100%;' onchange='sum();'>" +
                "       <?php echo Pajak();?>" +
                "       </select>" +
                "   </div>" +

i have other example and this without <?php $jsArray but. the result is same. my select2 is not working